# How to assign a module to different pages

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, sef, module-display

I have menus in home page. Now i want to display different modules in different page and also I want to add SEF custom name to pages. Since I am new to Joomla, Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To assign modules to pages;

**Joomla 2.5 instructions**

- Log into the Joomla administrator area of your site
- Select the Extensions menu and Module manager menu
- Open the module/menu you have created
- Scroll down to the bottom of the module position
- You will now see the menu assignment options where you can assign the
  module to selected pages or all pages
- To assign the module to all pages just select the all pages option
  from the drop down list
- To assign the module to select pages just select the selected pages
  option from the drop down list and then choose the pages you want to
  assign the module to.

**Joomla 3.x Instructions**

- Select the Extension menu and module manager menu
- Open the module/menu you have created for the slideshow
- Select the menu assignment tab
- You will now see a number of options where you can assign the module
  to all pages or only on selected pages

To enable SEF in Joomla follow the official docs [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_(SEF)_URLs).

**TIP**: *System Links/ Menu Item Alias* can be of great help to organize your menu. You can create several menus (show them or not in the frontsite), and create **aliases** to them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Advanced Module Manager](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager). With Advanced Module Manager you have the possibility to assign modules to just about anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

i understand you new to joomla.

it is easy to assign the modules to the different pages.
first go the modules and open it.
then go to the menu assignment.
then you can select the which page you want to show the module.

that good to see...

Have a nice Day...