# Assign a module to a page...but page doesn't show?

Tags: joomla-2.5, module

I am new to Joomla and learning it. I have a page which I need to assign a module to. I follow the steps [in this answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/4457/3425) but when I scroll down to assign the module to the page I want it to be assigned it doesn't appear.

The option is selected that it appears only on pages I want it to appear on. Then below that I `Menu Selection` and four tabs below that that list various pages. The page I am looking to assign the module to doesn't appear in that tab. How do I assign the module to a page? Or how do I make a page appear in one of those tabs so I can assign the module to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla is organized around menu items. For instance, if there is only a menu item for content to show articles, then all generated pages to navigate articles are going to have the same menu (Itemid).

To sum up, if you want to assign a module to a specific page, you need a menu item for that page.

- TIP: You can create a hidden menu, not shown in the site, just to single out a content item.
- ADVANCED TIP: Once you are familiar with the core organization, you can install a module manager like [Advanced Module Manager - NoNumber](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/style-a-design/modules-management/advanced-module-manager) to assign modules according to several conditions beyond menus.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to remind that, it is normally a menu that we assign the module not directly to the page, probably this is why you can not see it at the menus assginment tab.